# How to search nested dictionary in Python using returned values from user inputs

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, nested

I am looking for the most efficient means of returning a value within a nested dictionary.

At this point in the code, the Airline name (e.g. 'Delta') and the fare class (e.g. 'N') have already been inputted by the user and validated using re. The variables 'airline_name' and 'fare_class' are already defined. There are multiple fare classes that contain the same value; 'Delta' > 'F' 'J' > '2'

What would be the best way to search for a nested dictionary value (e.g. '1.5') using the passed in variable names 'airline_name' and 'fare_class'? Thanks for any and all feedback! (if I need to restructure my dict, I am more than happy to as well)

```
`FARE_CLASS_MULTIPLIER_DICTIONARY = {
'Delta': {
    ('N'): 0,
    ('E', 'H', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'Q', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W+', 'X'): 1,
    ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'I', 'P', 'W', 'Y', 'Z'): 1.5,
    ('F', 'J'): 2
        },
'United': {
    ('N'): 0,
    ('M', 'E', 'U', 'H', 'Q', 'V', 'W', 'S', 'T', 'L', 'K', 'G'): 1,
    ('Y', 'B'): 1.5,
    ('A', 'C', 'D', 'Z', 'P'): 2,
    ('F', 'J'): 3
        },
'American': {
    ('A'): 0,
    ('H', 'K', 'M', 'L', 'V', 'G', 'S', 'N', 'Q', 'O'): 1,
    ('Y', 'W', 'P'): 1.5,
    ('A', 'D', 'I', 'R'): 2,
    ('F', 'J'): 3
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to restructure your dict

Comment: What have you actually tried?

Comment: What do you mean by best?

Comment: Also note that `('N')` is the same as `'N'`, so your inner dicts have mixed types of keys

Comment: Yes replace `('N')` with `('N', )` to fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd restructure it so each fare_class was a key in a given airline's dictionary. So Delta's dictionary would become

```
'Delta': {
  'N': 0,

  'E': 1,
  'H': 1,
  'K': 1,
  'L': 1,
  'M': 1,
  'Q': 1,
  'S': 1,
  'T': 1,
  'U': 1,
  'V': 1,
  'W+': 1,
  'X': 1,

  'A': 1.5,
  'B': 1.5,
  'C': 1.5,
  'D': 1.5,
  'G': 1.5,
  'I': 1.5,
  'P': 1.5,
  'W': 1.5,
  'Y': 1.5,
  'Z': 1.5,

  'F': 2,
  'J': 2,
},
```

The multiplier can then be obtained with

```
multiplier = FARE_CLASS_MULTIPLIER_DICTIONARY[airline_name][fare_class]
```

Comment: That worked great, Thank you for the response and advice!!